# ¿Cómo pasar un predicado optimizable a una función?

Tags: c++, algoritmos, c++11, herencia, c++98

Tengo una clase que, reduciéndola a lo significativo para esta pregunta, es una extensión de `std::set` que permite obtener subconjuntos que cumplen un predicado.

```
#include <set>

class Predicado {
public:
  /** Devuelve true si n cumple el predicado
   * expresado por este objeto.
   */
  virtual bool cumple( int n ) const = 0;
};

class Conjunto : public std::set<int> {
  public:
    Conjunto( std::initializer_list<int> l):std::set<int>(l) {};
    Conjunto( ) {};
    /** Devuelve un conjunto con todos los elementos de este conjunto
     * que cumplen el predicado p
     */
    Conjunto subconjunto( const Predicado& p ) {
      Conjunto resultado;
      for ( int n : *this ) {
        if ( p.cumple(n))
          resultado.insert(n);
      }
      return resultado;
    }
};
```

Pero usarla resulta muy farragoso. Cada vez que quiero obtener un subconjunto usando un predicado nuevo tengo que hacer una clase nueva.

```
#include <iostream>

class SerPares : public Predicado {
public :
  virtual bool cumple( int n ) const {
    return (n&0x1) == 0;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Conjunto cto = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  Conjunto ctoPares = cto.subconjunto( SerPares() );

  std::cout << "Conjunto" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : cto ) 
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares ) 
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

Y además para crear un subconjunto hay que recorrer todos los miembros del conjunto original. Lo cual no siempre es necesario. Por ejemplo para la propiedad "Ser menor que 3" bastaría buscar [el límite inferior](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/) de 3 (que tiene coste logarítmico) y crear un conjunto con todos los elementos desde el principio hasta ese límite (que tiene coste lineal con el resultado en vez de lineal con el origen ).

¿Qué puedo hacer para que escribir una propiedad nueva sea menos farragoso consiguiendo además la mejor eficiencia posible? Indica en tu respuesta la mínima versión del standard que usas (c++98, c++11, c++14 o c++17).

Como hace ver asdasdasd en su respuesta el diseño del código de esta pregunta tiene graves fallos de diseño. Se permiten por tanto respuestas que modifiquen ese diseño. Siempre que podamos escribir algo similar a alguna de las siguientes :

```
Tipo cto = subconjunto( conjunto, predicado);

Tipo cto = conjunto.subconjunto( predicado );

Tipo cto = predicado.subconjunto( conjunto );
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero a destacar en la pregunta es el uso incorrecto de la herencia. No debe heredarse nunca de un contenedor de la STL ya que éstos no han sido diseñados para soportar dicha característica. La explicación rápida es que estos contenedores no disponen de un destructor virtual, lo que no garantiza que los recursos propios de la clase hija vayan a ser liberados convenientemente. Más información en este otro hilo: [¿Por qué no está bien derivar de contenedores standard?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23245/por-qu%C3%A9-no-est%C3%A1-bien-derivar-de-contenedores-standard) (enlace cortesía de @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos).

El problema del destructor también lo encontramos en la clase `Predicado`. No se ha declarado un destructor virtual por lo que va a sufrir la misma problemática.

Ante este tipo de problemas yo suelo recurrir a dos posibles soluciones:

La primera solución, pensada para ser lo más parecida a lo presentado en la pregunta, pasa por modificar la función `Conjunto` de tal forma que contenga internamente el contenedor. Si bien es una solución que requiere más trabajo, pues tenemos que dar acceso al conenedor para su manipulación, la solución garantiza la correcta liberación de recursos:

```
class Conjunto
{
  private:
    std::set<int> _contenedor;
};
```

Ahora, para proporcionar una la mayor flexibilidad a la hora de proporcionar predicados podemos optar por usar un functor en vez de una clase. Usar un functor nos permite no solo componer un predicado a partir de una clase sino también usar lambdas o funciones individuales:

```
Conjunto Conjunto::subconjunto( std::function<void(int)> functor )
{
  Conjunto resultado;
  for ( int n : *this ) {
    if ( functor(n))
      resultado.insert(n);
  return resultado;
}
```

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
struct Pares
{
  bool operator()(int valor)
  { return valor%2==0; }
};

bool FuncPares(int valor)
{
  return valor%2==0;
}

int main(int , char**)
{
  Conjunto cto = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  Conjunto ctoPares = cto.subconjunto( Pares() );
  Conjunto ctoPares2 = cto.subconjunto( FuncPares );
  Conjunto ctoPares3 = cto.subconjunto( [](int valor){return valor%2==0;} );

  std::cout << "Conjunto" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : cto )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (estructura)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (funcion independiente)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares2 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (lambda)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares3 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

Aun así, como he comentado al principio, no es una solución adecuada ya que obliga a tomar una decisión que no suele ser muy elegante:

- Crear un catálogo de funciones en `Conjunto` que den acceso a los diferentes métodos del contenedor (Mucho código a mantener e interfaz más compleja).
- Dar acceso al contenedor por referencia (adiós al encapsulamiento).

Para evitar estos problemas mi recomendación sería optar por una segunda solución:

En este caso, `Conjunto` desaparece. En su lugar vamos a crear una función que acepte un contenedor y un functor. La función va a devolver el subconjunto correspondiente:

```
std::set<int> subconjunto(
  const std::set<int>& conjunto,
  std::function<bool(int)> functor)
{
  std::set<int> resultado;
  for ( int n : conjunto) {
    if ( functor(n) )
      resultado.insert(n);
  return resultado;
}
```

Este prototipo inicial es completamente funcional y además compatible con los predicados que hemos creado para la primera solución. Si nos gustan los algoritmos de la STL también podemos dejarlo tal que:

```
std::set<int> subconjunto(
  const std::set<int>& conjunto,
  std::function<bool(int)> functor)
{
  std::set<int> resultado;
  std::copy_if(std::begin(conjunto),std::end(conjunto),
               std::inserter(resultado,resultado.begin()),
               functor);

  return resultado;
}
```

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
int main(int , char**)
{
  std::set<int> cto = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  auto ctoPares = subconjunto(cto,Pares());
  auto ctoPares2 = subconjunto(cto,FuncPares);
  auto ctoPares3 = subconjunto(cto,[](int valor){return valor%2==0;});

  std::cout << "Conjunto" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : cto )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (estructura)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (funcion independiente)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares2 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares (lambda)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares3 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

Como mejora se podría optar por templatizar la función, lo que permitiría reutilizar el código con vectores y listas. Una primera aproximación podría ser la siguiente:

```
template<class Contenedor, class Functor>
Contenedor subconjunto(
  const Contenedor& conjunto,
  Functor functor)
{
  Contenedor resultado;
  std::copy_if(std::begin(conjunto),std::end(conjunto),
               std::inserter(resultado,resultado.end()),
               functor);

  return resultado;
}

int main(int , char**)
{
  std::vector<int> cto = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  std::set<int> cto2 = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  auto ctoPares = subconjunto(cto,Pares());
  auto ctoPares2 = subconjunto(cto2,Pares());

  std::cout << "Conjunto (vector)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : cto )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto (vector)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Conjunto (set)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares2 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

**EDITO:**

Los ejemplos anteriores son compilables a partir de C++11. Para versiones anteriores `std::function` no está disponible. En su lugar se puede optar por templatizar la función:

```
template<class FuncPtr>
std::set<int> subconjunto(
  const std::set<int>& conjunto,
  FuncPtr functor)
{
  std::set<int> resultado;

  std::set<int>::const_iterator it, itEnd;

  for( it = conjunto.begin(), itEnd = conjunto.end(); it!=itEnd; ++it )
  {
    if( functor(*it) )
      resultado.insert(*it);
  }

  return resultado;
}

int main(int , char**)
{
  std::set<int> cto;

  cto.insert(11);
  cto.insert(252);
  cto.insert(31);
  cto.insert(2);

  std::set<int> ctoPares = subconjunto(cto,Pares());

  std::set<int>::const_iterator it, itEnd;

  std::cout << "Conjunto" << std::endl;
  for( it=cto.begin(), itEnd=cto.end(); it!=itEnd; ++it ) 
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Conjunto solo pares" << std::endl;
  for( it=ctoPares.begin(), itEnd=ctoPares.end(); it!=itEnd; ++it ) 
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

**EDITO 2:**

Conseguir que los predicados se puedan optimizar requiere actuar sobre el motor de búsqueda. La solución en este caso pasa por aislar el motor de búsqueda, lo que permitirá usar el que más nos interese en cada momento.

Siguiendo la dinámica de la respuesta una solución pasa por crear un catálogo de motores. Cada motor deberá implementar una función específica para poder ser utilizado. En este caso se trata del operador función:

```
// Realiza una búsqueda sobre todo el rango
struct MotorLineal
{
  MotorLineal() = default;

  std::set<int> operator()(
    const std::set<int>& conjunto,
    std::function<bool(int)> functor)
  {
    std::set<int> resultado;
    std::copy_if(conjunto.begin(),conjunto.end(),
                 std::inserter(resultado,resultado.end()),
                 functor);

    return resultado;
  }
};

// Empieza por el inicio del contenedor y se detiene cuando un elemento
// no concuerde con el predicado
struct MotorInicio
{
    std::set<int> operator()(
      const std::set<int>& conjunto,
      std::function<bool(int)> functor)
    {
      std::set<int> resultado;

      for( auto n : conjunto )
      {
        if( functor(n) )
          resultado.insert(n);
        else
          break;
      }

      return resultado;
    }
};
```

Ahora solo nos queda preparar la función `subconjunto` para que haga uso de los motores. En la mayoría de los casos necesitaremos iterar sobre toda la colección, por lo que podemos facilitar un poco el uso de la clase dejando este motor configurado "por defecto":

```
template<class Motor = MotorLineal>
std::set<int> subconjunto(
  const std::set<int>& conjunto,
  std::function<bool(int)> functor)
{
  Motor motor;
  return motor(conjunto,functor);
}
```

Y ahora la prueba de fuego:

```
int main(int , char**)
{
  std::set<int> cto = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  std::set<int> cto2 = { 11, 252 , 31, 2 };
  auto ctoPares = subconjunto(cto,Pares());
  auto ctoPares2 = subconjunto<MotorInicio>(cto2,Pares());

  std::cout << "Conjunto (motor por defecto)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Conjunto (optimizacion)" << std::endl;
  for ( auto i : ctoPares2 )
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

La salida del programa será la siguiente:

```
Conjunto (motor por defecto)
2
252
Conjunto (optimizacion)
2
```

Como se puede apreciar, al usar `MotorInicio` únicamente obtenemos un resultado. Esto es porque el segundo valor a chequear es el 11 y dicho valor no es par, luego el motor de búsqueda se detendrá en ese momento.

La guinda del pastel sería preparar este cambio para que admitiese múltiples contenedores, pero esta parte ya se escapa demasiado del ámbito de la pregunta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta (+1). A lo único a lo que no responde es a cómo hacer optimizable el Predicado (o functor). Es decir, si el functor es "elementos menores que 3" es posible obtener un subconjunto de forma más eficiente que iterando sobre todo el conjunto original. Me gustaría un esquema como el que propones, en que una función calcula el subconjunto iterando todo el conjunto contra un functor, pero en el que fuese posible dar "functores especializados"  para casos particulares como "menor que 3".

Comment: Cierto, ya está editada la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: ¡Excelente! No estaba muy convencido de que fuese posible una llamada a subconjunto tan compacta que permita especificar algoritmos optimizados (motores) y que permita predicados sin definir clases (lambdas). Y abreviando más si quieres el motor por defecto. Me quito el sombrero ante tu maestría en C++.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: `La explicación rápida es que estos contenedores no disponen de un destructor virtual, lo que no garantiza que los recursos propios de la clase hija vayan a ser liberados convenientemente` En realidad, lo único que se garantiza es `Undefined Behavior`.

Answer (score 1):

En principio, esta es mas bien una *no respuesta*: No está bien derivar de clases que no fueron hechas para que se derive de ellas (contenedores estándar). Podría usarse composición, aunque ahora no veo la ventaja.

Una solución que me gusta es con los algoritmos estándar y funciones libres, o closures, o expresiones lambda, o los "functors" que solían verse en C++98, creo.

Te paso una forma de determinar los dos subconjuntos de tu ejemplo, usando C++11, que del 98 ya no me acuerdo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void mostrar(const std::string& titulo, const std::set<int>& set)
{
    std::cout << titulo << ": ";
    for(const auto& i : set)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99 };

    std::set <int> pares;
    std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::inserter(pares, pares.end()), 
                [](int i){ return (i&1) == 0; });

    mostrar("pares", pares);

    std::set<int> menores_que_3;
    std::copy(s.begin(), std::upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), 2),
              std::inserter(menores_que_3, menores_que_3.end()));

    mostrar("menores_que_3", menores_que_3);

}
```

Comment: Cuando una pregunta se basa en una premisa errónea es mucho más útil hacer ver ese error que dar una respuesta que se ajusta a la pregunta pero que persiste en el error. Muchas gracias. [¿Por qué no está bien derivar de contenedores standard?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23245/por-qu%c3%a9-no-est%c3%a1-bien-derivar-de-contenedores-standard)