# ¿Por qué no está bien derivar de contenedores standard?

Tags: c++, herencia

La pregunta surge de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23235/301).

> No está bien derivar de clases que no fueron hechas para que se derive
>   de ellas (contenedores estándar). Podría usarse composición, aunque
>   ahora no veo la ventaja.

¿Es así?

¿Que inconvenientes tiene derivar de un contenedor standard como, por ejemplo, std::set?

¿Por qué es preferible la composición?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > No está bien derivar de clases que no fueron hechas para que se derive de ellas (contenedores estándar). Podría usarse composición, aunque ahora no veo la ventaja.
>
> ¿Es así?

Lo es. [La respuesta de asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23196/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-un-predicado-optimizable-a-una-funci%c3%b3n/23235#23235) hace mención explícita a no derivar de contenedores estándar pero puede ser extrapolada a cualquier otro objeto sea contenedor o no, sea estándar o no.

Así que el resto de respuesta estará enfocada (salvo que se mencione lo contrario) en el hecho de que no debe derivarse de clases que no estén preparadas para ser derivadas.

#### Posibles fallos al destruir los objetos.

Cuando una clase (por ejemplo: un contenedor) maneja recursos (por ejemplo memoria), debe ser responsable de liberar dichos recursos, [preferentemente en su destructor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

El destructor del objeto es invocado automáticamente cuando éste fue creado en espacio automático (stack) y se abandona el ámbito donde fue creado. Si el objeto fue creado mediante `new` en espacio dinámico (heap) es necesario llamar al destructor mediante la instrucción `delete` y es entonces cuando las cosas se complican.

Podemos almacenar una clase derivada en un puntero a una clase base, así que el siguiente código es legal pero peligroso:

```
class Conjunto : public std::set<int> { using std::set<int>::set; };
std::set<int> *c = new Conjunto { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
delete c;
```

El peligro reside en que el [destructor de `std::set`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/%7Eset) no es virtual. Esto provoca que al destruir un `Conjunto` mediante un puntero a su clase base `std::set<int>` no se invoque el destructor de la case base y por ello: toda la memoria solicitada por la clase base queda sin liberar. Eso si, no pasa nada si `Conjuto` se borra mediante puntero a su tipo o si se aloja en stack:

```
{
    Conjunto c { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Conjunto *d = new Conjunto { c };
    std::set<int> *e = new Conjunto { c };

    // Se borra d, desde puntero a Conjunto: Ningun problema!
    delete d;
    // Se borra e, desde puntero a Conjunto: Ningun problema!
    delete static_cast<Conjunto>(e);Conjunto
}   // Se borra c automaticamente: Ningun problema!
```

Dado que no se puede modificar la implementación de objetos de librerías ajenas<sup>1</sup>, nos es imposible corregir el *problema* de la no-virtualidad del destructor del `std::set<int>` y por ello podemos causar fugas de memoria pero...

#### ¿Y si no quiero usar la clase desde su base?

> ¿Que inconvenientes tiene derivar de un contenedor standard como, por ejemplo, std::set?

Supongamos que no pretendes usar tu clase de forma polimórfica, esto soluciona el problema de la ausencia de destructor virtual. Para que esto sea posible deberíamos empezar por cambiar el tipo de herencia a privado:

```
class Conjunto : private std::set<int> { using std::set<int>::set; };
// ERROR! Clase base inaccesible. No se puede asignar Conjunto a set.
std::set<int> *c = new Conjunto { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

¿Es este uso aconsejable? Podría serlo en algunos contextos pero yo sigo sin aconsejarlo<sup>2</sup> ya que puede romper el [principio de la mínima sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_M%C3%ADnima_Sorpresa); como programador yo esperaría que una clase que derive de `std::set` pueda ser usada igual que un `std::set` (construida igual, recorrida igual, gestionada igual); incluso si es una extensión de dicho contenedor tal vez incluso me plantee usarla en lugar del `std::set` el no poder hacerlo sería "*sorprendente*".

#### ¿Qué aconsejas?<sup>2</sup>

Si una clase se comporta exáctamente igual que otra salvo por unas operaciones determinadas tenemos diferentes opciones:

- Derivar.
- Extender.
- Componer.

Ya hemos visto pros y contras de derivar, yo no lo consideraría una opción prohibida pero tampoco sería mi primera opción; hay que pensar bien antes de usarla.

C++ no dispone de [extensión de clases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb383977.aspx), pero se pueden especializar funciones para tratar con ciertos tipos y realizar operaciones determinadas sobre ellos:

```
// Alias de tipo, Conjunto es un set de enteros.
using Conjunto = std::set<int>;

// Funcion que recibe Conjunto como parametro
void haz_cosas(Conjunto &) { std::cout << "Es un conjunto\n"; }

// Funcion que recibe otros tipos de set como parametro
template <typename T>
void haz_cosas(std::set<T> &) { std::cout << "Esto es otra cosa\n"; }

Conjunto c { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::set<int> s { 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::set<float> f { .1f, .2f, .3f, .4f };

haz_cosas(c); // Muestra: Es un conjunto
haz_cosas(s); // Muestra: Es un conjunto
haz_cosas(f); // Muestra: Esto es otra cosa
```

Por desgracia C++ no dispone ([aún](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0109r0.pdf)) de alias opacos, así que la especialización de `haz_cosas` no distingue entre `Conjunto` o `std::set<int>`.

La composición soluciona el problema de la ausencia de alias opacos y esquiva los problemas relacionados con la herencia:

```
// Contiene un set de enteros.
class Conjunto {
    std::set<int> datos;
    // miembros especificos
};

// Funcion que recibe Conjunto como parametro
void haz_cosas(Conjunto &) { std::cout << "Es un conjunto\n"; }

// Funcion que recibe otros tipos de set como parametro
template <typename T>
void haz_cosas(std::set<T> &) { std::cout << "Esto es otra cosa\n"; }

Conjunto c { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::set<int> s { 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::set<float> f { .1f, .2f, .3f, .4f };

haz_cosas(c); // Muestra: Es un conjunto
haz_cosas(s); // Muestra: Esto es otra cosa
haz_cosas(f); // Muestra: Esto es otra cosa
```

> ¿Por qué es preferible la composición?

No creo que una opción sea preferible frente a otra, cada una de las opciones tiene pros y contras a tener en cuenta y dependerá del uso que se quiera dar al tipo el decidir sobre una u otra.

---

<sup>1</sup>Poderse se puede... pero ¿se debe?.

<sup>2</sup>Es una opinión personal, no debe considerarse un mandamiento.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Es cierto que la [herencia privada no es aconsejable (en inglés)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7209089/956880), pero no diría que sea sorprendente el que una clase que hereda privadamente no se pueda usar en lugar de la clase base. Es parte de la especificación del lenguaje el que esto es así. Yo omitiría esa parte, dejando como mucho una recomendación de no usar herencia privada con un enlace a los motivos para el que quiera detalles.

Comment: En el propio enlace que has facilitado: "*Usa composición cuando puedas, herencia privada cuando debas*". Eso es también la filosofía que intento inculcar en mi respuesta: "**No creo que una opción sea preferible frente a otra**, cada una de las opciones tiene pros y contras a tener en cuenta y **dependerá del uso que se quiera dar al tipo el decidir sobre una u otra**". :P

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos me acabo de dar cuenta que entendí mal tu mensaje, me ocuparé de editar la respuesta próximamente.